# Unity: Creating a gameobject list for a puzzle game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with a difficulty I have with lists.
Basically I need a code that allows me to check a list of game objects, there are 4 in all, which are destroyed by the player when the player interacts, allowing the player to exit the level.
Thank you in advance that you manage to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you have is

```
public List<GameObject> theList;
```

and now you want to check if all of the items in this list have been destroyed / there is any item in the list which is not destroyed yet.

You can either use a simple loop like e.g.

```
public bool CheckAllDestroyed()
{
    // fo through all items in he list
    foreach(var item in theList)
    {
        // use the implicit bool operator
        // -> Does this object exist and is it currently alive?
        if(item)
        {
            // If this is the fall they are NOT all destroyed yet
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Otherwise there either were no items at all or they are all destroyed
    return true;
}
```

You can also use Linq and do the same in a single query:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public bool CheckAllDestroyed()
{
    // Is there any item in the list which is alive?
    // If not there either are no items at all or all are destroyed already
    return !theList.Any(item => item);
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for the help, in fact it was what I was missing in the script.
The only thing I didn't understand is the comment "// use the implicit bool operator", should I insert a boolean variable to indicate the destruction of the list objects or something?
Excuse me for ignorance

Comment: `UnityEngine.Object` **has/provides** the [implicit bool operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html). You don't have to add anything, just use it. You could also use `if(item != null)`